# phpmyadmin store result after query execution

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table on my PHPMyAdmin DB with 3 fields: DateStart (datetime type), DateEnd (datetime type), DIff(INT)
I want to store minutes of difference in Diff field.

I know how to get the difference :

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,DateStart,DateEnd)as Diff FROM `calc`
```

but how can I execute this query automatically and store the result in the database?

Comment: Though this is a bad idea, you can add trigger on your table to calculate this on the fly

Comment: @Akina this wouldn't be done automatically as required by a question

Comment: Drop column `Diff`. Create generated column instead. ```ALTER TABLE calc DROP COLUMN `Diff`, ADD COLUMN `Diff` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DateStart, DateEnd)) STORED;```

Comment: @Akina is working thank you result are stored.